# Django STATIC_URL = '/'

Tags: python, django, django-contrib

I would like to serve static files in my Django application directly from the root.

If i set:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

all works as expected. However I would like to serve files from the '/' of my site without having to access the 'static' subfolder.

Is that possible? If I set:

```
STATIC_URL = '/'
```

I receive code 404 and this error:

```
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
```

Comment: More information required. Is this in development? How are you serving your static files?

Answer (score 1):

just to make sure- you are not confusing the following:

`STATIC_ROOT` refers to where you put your static files

`STATIC_URL` refers to where queries over the internet will get your static assets (eg: www.abc.com/static/jquery.js)

if you do indeed mean `STATIC_URL`, then it sounds like it could cause a lot of trouble, because then your static files might have the same name as a url pattern that you have defined for one of the views.

Comment: for the STATIC_URL case, i would probably put a catchall url pattern at the bottom of the main urls.py patterns list (keep in mind that anything that matches first gets pointed to the views function so only stuff that is not matched gets trickled down)


then you can have your view function serve up the corresponding static file.


but that does sound pretty hacky/not the best way

Comment: I do mean `STATIC_URL`, I am trying to serve from Django an AngularJS app that comes shipped to work on the root and not on a subfolder.

Comment: also, then later on, you won't be able to separate out the static content to a different server easily

Comment: The statics are hardcoded to be on local server on the AngularJS app anyway... But I get your point. Setting `STATIC_URL` would have been the fastest solution to my problem, but if that is not possible I'll try to search replace the AngularJS app for all inclusions of static prepending the `static var` coming from Django.

Comment: how would you do to serve those statics with the catchall url? I think I could use `r'^.*'` something like this as url regexp but what should I do in the view?

Comment: look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups). then you can pass the static file requested as a param into the view